# When is my Wasserstein GAN-GP overfitting?

Tags: neural-networks, computer-vision, generative-models, gan, wasserstein

I have a hard time interpreting the WGAN-GP losses attached. At which epoch is D and/or G overfitting? The quality improves a lot overtime, yet the generator loss at later epochs does not appear on par with what I observe from generator samples (truncation trick) at later epochs… The data is 3000 images of one class.

[image: D/G Losses]

Answer (score 0):

Have you run your model on a simple dataset like MNIST to verify it's implemented correctly?

In an WGAN-GP, the generator loss is typically not meaningful, and the discriminator loss is an approximation of the negative wasserstein distance between the generator distribution and real distribution.

Of course, this only works if the discriminator is powerful enough, and you train it enough (usually several iterations per generator iteration). Otherwise, the discriminator loss is pretty meaningless.

When it's working properly, the discriminator loss should start from 0, rapidly drop to some negative number, and then slowly work it's way back to 0, (which means the generator and true distribution are getting closer).

Comment: Have you run your model on a simple dataset like MNIST to verify it's implemented correctly?

-Yes, it is based on this: https://github.com/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/generative/wgan_gp.py

- Would your answer apply to this particular implementation ? I don't see signs of this kind of behavior on the demo either, especially in my case where it is a one class target.

PS: Thank you very much for the insightful answer.